# How to debug J2ME Application on Device using NetBeans

Tags: debugging, netbeans, printing, java-me, bluetooth

I want to debug my application step by step on Device. My Application contains Bluetooth and Printer code so It is necessary for me to test my application on Device only. How can I debug my Application on Device and my Log can be seen in Netbeans. Is there any solution for that? I got Exception somewhere but I am not getting where the Problem is. So Please help me if you have any idea. Thanks..

Comment: you can use nokia Asha SDK that has plugin for on device debug

Comment: @Saurav.. Thank you for your reply.. But I dont have Nokia Asha. And I want to debug an application on multiple Device like Nokia 200, Nokia c3 etc. as I have to test an app on these devices.